# Confidence intervals of asymptotic level?

Tags: confidence-interval

My professor posted a slide which said:

> Let $(E, (\mathbb{P}_\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta})$ be a statistical model based on observations $X_1, \cdots, X_n$, and assume $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.
>
> Confidence interval of level $1 - \alpha$ for $\theta$:  Any random (i.e., depending on $X_1, \cdots, X_n$) interval $\mathcal{I}$ whose boundaries do not depend on $\theta$ and such that $\mathbb{P}_\theta[\mathcal{I} \ni \theta] \geq 1 - \alpha, \forall \theta \in \Theta$.
>
> Confidence interval of asymptotic level $1 - \alpha$ for $\theta$:  Any random (i.e., depending on $X_1, \cdots, X_n$) interval $\mathcal{I}$ whose boundaries do not depend on $\theta$ and such that $\mathbb{P}_\theta[\mathcal{I} \ni \theta] \geq 1 - \alpha, \forall \theta \in \Theta$.

What's the difference between these two intervals?  I looked up a definition of asymptotic, so my guess is that he meant to write something like

> $\mathbb{P}[\mathcal{I} \ni \theta] \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{} 1 - \alpha$

for the second interval, but I'm not sure.